# How to use session variable from one TS file to another TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I have session variable in `home.component.ts` named `session`. I want to use this variable in `user.compnent.ts` and also in `dashboard.component.ts`. Below is my session variable in `home.component.ts` :

```
var session = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
```

and below is my code in `user.component.ts`:

```
import { HomeComponent } from '../Components/home.component';
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _userService: UserService, 
private _HomeComponent: HomeComponent, private router: Router) { }
```

But I couldn't get the session. I'm new to `Angular`.

Comment: you can use `localStorage` or `redux` or `shared service`.

Comment: You'll have to use `sessionStorage.getItem('session')` again in other components unless you want to use a shared service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: In you home.components you're getting data from session storage. First you need store the data. Use .setItem('NAME OF SESSION STORATE', DATA) and then you can get the data stored in you session storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are alreayd using **[`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**, the variables stored in will be accessible throught the page. so you need the following in the **`dashboard.component.ts`**

```
var session = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
```

Comment: yes i dont know how to access thin in another TS file.

Comment: @Vijay this is how you access! since its store in sessionstorage

Comment: Sorry I thought it works only within a page. Thanks for your support dude its working.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi I was trying something similar, I am able to get session data in component.ts but  is there a way to get session data in storage.service.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

Shared service is the best way.  [See this article](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2019/04/23/how-to-use-angular-services-to-share-data-between-components/)